# Column Space of A

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the matrix 
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 &6 \\
-8 &-12\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
and the vector $b = \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-6 
\end{bmatrix}
$.
So I am tying to determine whether b lies in the column space of A. My answer for this problem is yes since the row 2 of the matrix and the vector is a multiple of -2 giving us infinitly many answers since it is parallel. First, is my answer correct? If so, what I am confused with is with 3x3 matrix. For the following matrix, 
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 &-6 &-6\\
4 &2 &-8\\
6 &-2 &-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
and the following vector
$b = \begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
-14\\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
, can someone show me how you decide whether b lies in the column space of A? For the above matrix, I made the problem up myself. So feel free to demonstrate you point in any matrix you feel like. What I am having a bit of trouble at the moment is grasping the mechanics of how in general this is determined. Any inutitive explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "since the row 2 of the matrix and the vector is a multiple of -2." Can you clarify?

Comment: @Jlhglkj Glkjgh: What is the definition of the column space of a matrix?

Comment: Multiply the entire row 1 of matrix A and vector b by -2 and you get row 2. So (-2)*4=-8. (-2)*6=-12. (-2)*3=-6.

Comment: Okay, that's true. What does that have to do with the vector?

Comment: Well I don't think it does. I was trying to explain my point of how the row 2 of matrix A is a multiple of row 1 * -2.

Comment: Ah! Well, you didn't mention row 1 at all....

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that $b$ in the first case is a multiple of the second column of your first matrix: $1/2$ Column 2 = b. So essentially $b = 0\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix} + \frac 12 \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ -12\end{pmatrix}$. Indeed, we see that any vector of the form $\langle t, -2t\rangle $ is in the column space of the matrix.

Hint: Solve the augmented Matrix $[A \mid b]$ to see if a solution exists for the constants $c_1, c_2, c_3$. If so, you will know that $b$ is in the column space of $A$.

$$b = c_1\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ \end{pmatrix}
 + c_2\begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 2 \\ -2 \\ \end{pmatrix}
+ c_3\begin{pmatrix}-6 \\ -8 \\ -2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$[A\mid b] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 &-6 &-6 &-4 \\
    4 &2 &-8 &-14\\
    6 &-2 &-2 &4
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: It doesnt need to be unique, just exist.

Comment: I realize that...it need only exist, yes.

Comment: @Amzoti I've got to get augmented matrices down pat! (I improvised, a poor improvisation.)

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks...I have to remember the "array" thang!

Comment: @amWhy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584022/how-do-i-render-an-augmented-matrix-with-mathjax

Comment: Jlhglkj Glkjhg: are you still looking for help on the question you posted earlier today?

Answer (score 1):

If $b$ is in Col$A = \text{Col}\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-6 &-6\\
4 &2 &-8\\
6 &-2 &-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

then $b= c_1\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
4 \\
6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 + c_2\begin{bmatrix}
-6 \\
2 \\
-2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ c_3\begin{bmatrix}
-6 \\
-8 \\
-2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-6 &-6\\
4 &2 &-8\\
6 &-2 &-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

For some $c_1, c_2,$ and $c_3$
so being in the column space is the same as having a solution to the system $Ax=b$

Comment: Does that mean if I solve it in its augmented form and determine that a solution is possible, I can tell if vector b is the column space of A?

Comment: Exactly Right...

Comment: Just to make sure I understood correctly, I solve it in the form of [A b] and go bout determining if b lies in the column space of A, correct?

Comment: Yea, you do not even need to solve it all the way out if you are just trying to determine if it is in the column space, if you can show [A b] has any solution then b is in ColA

Comment: @SeanBallentine In your last line, you have the matrix/vector product in the wrong order. It should be $b=Ac$.